# Comparing dates of two files in shell

Tags: shell

I have two files created at different times.

In my shell scripting program, I want to initialize a variable with the date of the file which was created earlier.

For eg. if file1 was created on 22 April and file2 was created on April 19. my variable should be initialized to 19th April.

How can I do this in bash shell?

Comment: belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Assuming existence of GNU `stat` (part of GNU coreutils):

```
if [[ $(stat -c%W <file1>) -lt $(stat -c%W <file2>) ]]
then
    EARLIER="$(stat -c%w <file1>)"
else
    EARLIER="$(stat -c%w <file1>)"
fi
```

Note the case of `%W` (integer) vs. `%w` (human-readable) is significant.

`%W` / `%w` is birth time, since you asked for "creation time". Usually `%Y` / `%y` (last modification) or `%Z` / `%z` (last change) are more meaningful.

If you need a different format for your date, you could feed the `stat` output to `date`, e.g.:

```
date -d "$(stat -c%w <earlier_file>)" +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

**PS:** While you are at the subject of time stamps, please consider [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339) for your formatting, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:DD-TZ, which is non-ambiguous, portable, and sortable.

Answer (score -1):

`/bin/date` can [convert to timestamps](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?date++NetBSD-current), using the `%s` format, after which date comparison is a straight numeric compare, so the solution to your problem, modulo syntax errors, is:

```
DATE1=`date -j '22 April' +"%d %B"`
DATE2=`date -j '19 April' +"%d %B"`
if [[ $DATE2 < $DATE1 ]]; then
    export VAR=`date -j $DATE1 +"%s"`
else
    export VAR=`date -j $DATE2 +"%s"`
fi
```

Comment: sudo? Why would you need root privileges to convert a date?

Comment: Because I was using the wrong system's manpage and wasn't working. In any event, the downvote was unwarranted, *especially* given that your solution was not provided.

Comment: Still using sudo in the export.

Comment: 1) The `-j` option is for BSD `date`, and not present in GNU coreutils' `date`. 2) This doesn't answer the part about how to *get* the creation time of a file. 3) You don't have to provide an own solution to downvote others.

Comment: OP never said which `date` command he was using. OP did not ask how to get a file's creation time. While you don't **have to**, I consider it good form if you do.

Comment: "I want to initialize a variable with the date of the file which was created earlier." And the OP wasn't specifying which `/bin/date` he's using because he wasn't talking about `/bin/date` in the first place. -1 for weaseling instead of improving your answer.